# Can 'social distancing' between different types of pedestrians be changed?

Tags: anylogic

In a pedestrian model, I am trying to simulate how regular people act in the presence of a wheelchair user where they (usually) provide ample space (~0.5m) around the wheelchair user, you could call it a kind of 'social distance'.

Is it possible to change how much distance one type of pedestrian (i.e. regular person) keeps from another type (i.e. wheelchair user)? Are there any appropriate parameters which could be added?

Answer (score 0):

Pedestrians have a setting for their "diameter". Use several pedestrian agent types and change it accordingly.

If you don't know how to create different agent types, do the step-by-step tutorials, they show this and much more: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html